# Unit test method controller call with inheritance

Tags: unit-testing, grails, spock

I have a XXXController that is a subclass of a baseController.
I want to test the xxxController and I need to stub one method call from the baseController.

I have tried something like that:

```
controller.xxxMethod(_) >> false
```

but It's not working.

Anybody knows how to stub a baseController method call in the subClass using Spock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to mock/stub the class under test, which is an anti-pattern. I would tell you to look at Spies and partial mocks (http://spock-framework.readthedocs.org/en/latest/interaction_based_testing.html#partial-mocks) but as you can see, even the official documentation says "Think twice before using this feature."

So my suggestion is to refactor your code where the class under test is a real class and only collaborators are mocked/stubbed.